# Deserializing json issue - inherited linq2SQL object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, deserialization, anonymous-methods

I have used Linq-to-SQL objects in my web app. My base and inherited classes look like this:

```
//Base Class: this will define the attributes that is auto-generated
//when using Linq-2-SQL ORM. Note this class is a partial class
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Categories")]
[global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
public partial class Category : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged 


//Inherited Class:
[Serializable]
public class CategoryEntity : Category
{
    private int _ActiveAdsCount;

    public int ActiveAdsCount
    {
        get
        {
            return _ActiveAdsCount;
        }

        set
        {
            _ActiveAdsCount = value;
        }
    }

    public int DisplaySequence { get; set; }

}
```

when serialize, the Json OUTPUT is (note the ActiveAdsCount and DisplaySequence values):

[{"ActiveAdsCount":3429,"DisplaySequence":99,"CategoryID":636,"ParentCategoryID":635,"CategoryName":"propForRent","CategoryImageFN":null}]

When I am calling the deserialze object method

```
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseText);
```

where T is List
Result: it shows "ActiveAdsCount" and "DisplaySequence" have 0 values while the json shows proper correct information coming from Database. So, the problem is in deserialization.

I am using 4.5.1 version of Newtonsoft.Json.dll of .Net 4.0 framework

Comment: Have a look at a similar problem posted here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987302/deserialize-classes-which-inherit-from-superclass-with-json-net

Comment: Yupp it works like a charm :)
@JasonJong Thanks very much buddy, God BLESS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moreover, I have marked my CategoryEntity class with DataContract attribute and its members to Datamember for serialization purpose. I notice that the Serialization attribute is making only the instance as serializable but not its members. So, the new class look like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class CategoryEntity : Category
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ActiveAdsCount { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int DisplaySequence { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IList<CategoryEntity> SubCategories { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IList<BasicCategoryInfo> SubCategoriesBasicInfoList { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ParentCategoryNameEn { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int CityID { get; set; }
}
```

@JasonJong Thanks very much for your comment.