# JSON.NET DeserializeObject from array by order to a list

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to Deserialize a Json Object into Dynamic List by order, so I have:

Json:

```
   string json = "{'elements':[
                     {'EntityA':[
                               {'name ':'Jhon'}
                               ],
                      'EntityB':[
                               {'title' : 'car'}
                               ],
                      'EntityB':[
                               {'title':'aaa'}
                               ],
                      'EntityA':[
                               {'name' : 'Alice'}
                               ]]}";
```

.NET Classes Base Classes:

```
public interface EntitysInterface{}

public class EntityA: EntitysInterface
{
   public string name { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB: EntitysInterface
{
   public string title { get; set; }
}

public class Entitys
{
    public List<EntitysInterface> elements { get; set; } //EntityA, EntityB,...

    public Entitys() 
    {
    }
}
```

My DeserializeObject Dificult:

```
Entitys listFinaly = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entitys>(json);
```

**Exception "Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. :( "**

Comment: Maybe, I would try to help if `JsonConvert` wouldn't have thrown exception while parsing your json string

Answer (score 2):

The JSON.NET deserializer is telling you that it can't figure out which `EntitysInterface` object that you would like selected.  It requires that you give it a hint.

`ContractResolver` helps to give that hint.

[This post answers a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987302/deserialize-classes-which-inherit-from-superclass-with-json-net)

EDIT:

There is a [good example](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm) in the JSON.Net documentation.